# How to create separate log file for each server instance running in the jboss domain mode

Tags: jboss, log4j2

I'm using jboss 7.2,and I created a log4j2.xml and placed in the server, application running in the domain mode there are two server instance in each ip, application logs are printing only for one server instance and another server instance logs are not printing,how to print the both server instance logs are in separate files.

Is anyone having idea pls help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry....you cannot use log4j2 in JBoss7.2.

Only [WildFly 22](https://www.wildfly.org/news/2021/01/13/WildFly22-Final-Released/) supports Log4j2 out of the box.

However, you may implement Log4j2 to other versions of WildFly, according to this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-log/how-to-use-log4j2-in-your-wildfly-applications/?amp=1). However I did not try myself.